# opening file with vim creates a new file although the file exists

Tags: php, apache, vim

I am trying to read the apache error log in `var/log`. I have an `error.log` file there, but when I `sudo vim` it a new `error.log` file is created. I'm pretty sure there should be something in there as I'm trying to debug a 500 internal server error.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood what the problem was, I had to do `sudo vim apache2/error.log` instead of `sudo ls apache2` followed by `sudo vim error.log`.

Comment: So, if this was a misunderstanding on your side, I suggest to delete the question, as this is unlikely to help other users.

Comment: @IngoKarkat you might be right, where can I do that?

Comment: I don't think it is possible for him to delete it at this point (since other people have answered). I think you can try flagging a moderator.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might be a path. Try giving vim the full file path (or double-check the relative path) otherwise it looks in the current directory for the specified file and if it isn't there it assumes you want to create it.

```
sudo vim /full/path/to/error.log
```

or

```
sudo vim ./relative/path/to/error.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use

```
$ sudo vim filename
```

use

```
$ sudo -e filename
```

And I think you have a working directory issue, either use the file's full path:

```
$ sudo -e /path/to/filename
```

or navigate to the directory and use it's relative path:

```
$ cd /path/to
$ sudo -e /path/to/filename
```